# Detecting corrupted images in bash script

Tags: bash, image-processing, png

I have >2000 images from a webcam stream (for a time-lapse video), I need to delete all incomplete & corrupted images, before passing them to a php-gd script that edits them for the final video.

Is it possible to detect corrupted files with imagemagick or some other tool? If i try to open the corrupted image with feh it displays `libpng error: Read Error` in console

Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE:** It seems that the suggested identify method accepts the bad images in my case. Here is an example of a corrupted one http://imgur.com/YcB9n

Comment: Same issue with `identify` here. It accepts images that *are* in fact incomplete.

Comment: What does closing this as "too broad" say about narrow-mindedness of voters? Seems like a perfectly adequate question to me.

Comment: By default, "identify" only looks at the image header, and therefore won't detect corruption within the image data.  Use "identify -verbose" to scan the entire image file.

Comment: This might be a good question on [su], but not here, because no programming is involved, or even requested.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Try ImageMagick's `identify` command. From the man page:

> Identify describes the format and
>   characteristics of one or more image
>   files. It will also report if an image
>   is incomplete or corrupt.

**Example:**

```
$ identify foo.png
identify: NotAPNGImageFile (foo.png).

$ echo $?
1
```

An alternative, is to use **PIL (Python Imaging Library)**:

```
from PIL import Image

im = Image.open("foo.png")
im.verify()
```

From the [documentation](http://www.pythonware.com/library/pil/handbook/image.htm):

> im.verify()
>
> Attempts to determine if the file is
>   broken, without actually decoding the
>   image data. If this method finds any
>   problems, it raises suitable
>   exceptions. This method only works on
>   a newly opened image; if the image has
>   already been loaded, the result is
>   undefined. Also, if you need to load
>   the image after using this method, you
>   must reopen the image file.

Comment: Love the `identify` command-line. Thank you so much! You saved my buttock!

Comment: I can confirm that, as reported by the OP, `identify` also often accepts images that are decidedly incomplete.

Comment: use -verbose flag to output errors and warnings

Answer (score 11):

I tried the ImageMagick `identify` command on a jpg I had laying around with several kinds of corruptions thrown in. It was able to identify some, but not all, so this might just be a partial solution at best, but try this:

```
for f in *.JPG ; do identify $f > /dev/null || echo $f >> /tmp/fail ; done ; cat /tmp/fail
```