# OpenCV imshow doesn't prompt window showing the image

Tags: python, opencv

I've been using OpenCV for a while and never had any problems until today.
Here is the code I use trying to show the image:

```
img = cv2.imread('im0.png')
cv2.imshow("CTest", img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

What I tried & what I know:

- checked the relative and absolute path of the image, it's fine
- printed the image array - it works
- tried displaying the image using matplotlib - it works
- changed `cv.2waitKey(0)` to `cv2.waitKey(1000)` just to see - nothing happens
- the opencv `cv2.imread` works

When running my code, Python is started but no window/image appears...

I've been through every question and forum similar to mine and I still don't know what's wrong.
I am using PyCharm and Python version 3.9.0 on a Mac running BigSur 11.0.1, the OpenCV version is 4.4.0.

I have deleted and reinstalled both Python and PyCharm and OpenCV, it doesn't work.

Comment: Does any of your old code still work?  have you tried other image files?  Have you tried using an absolute path to your image?

Comment: Yes, I've tried my old codes, they don't work anymore, I have also tried using an absolute path and I get the same result; namely nothing...I have also tried other image files, nothing works, I am so confused...

Comment: Maybe it's a problem with a new version of OpenCV, try using 'specify version' and selecting an earlier version in the project settings.

Comment: maybe check if the image is corrupt? e.g. linux identify im0.png  https://stackoverflow.com/a/4780718/14105642

Comment: I uninstalled Opencv and reinstalled an older version, it works as expected now! Thank you so much! I really didn't think about that.

Comment: No worries, if you're using PyCharm you can downgrade it from the project settings, you shouldn't have to use pip.. I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update:
Uninstalling Opencv using the following terminal command:

`pip uninstall opencv-python`

And reinstalling an older version did the job.

Remember that Opencv is quite a large library thus it may take some time to reinstall it.